# UIButton Rounded Rect unwanted 3D effect

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I had a couple of UIButtons on a nib of type RoundedRect which before iOS 6 looked nice and flat.  In iOS 6 though they've acquired a 3D effect border which I cannot get rid of (I'd supply a pic but my reputation is too puny).  Can anybody suggest how to get the nice flat look back?

I'm sure this will turn out to be the stupidest question I've ever asked and that the answer will be so simple I'll kick myself for a week. But I can't find it and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried taking the button as custom and then setting image on it.

Comment: Have you tried with layers of button.USING LAYER we can set the color for border & shadow of button

Comment: Thanks for your comments, yes I knew I could go down the route of a custom button, but in this instance it was just annoying me - I thought I was probably missing a simple property setting and am relieved at least to know it wasn't something that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why that effect appeared , but one way to do this is to avoid Rounded Rect. 
I always use custom buttons. You can customize them in code in any way you want .

For example:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 8;  //this gives it rounded corners
button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor] ; // this is how you set a border
button.layer.borderWidth = 2; //this is how you set the width of the border
```

The layer member of the UIButton is a CALayer and you can set shadows to it . [This](http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths) is a good tutorial.

You can also add a gradient background in order to make the button nicer , like this:

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.9] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.8] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.7] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.6] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.5] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.4] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.3] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.2] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.1] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:skinRed green:skinGreen blue:skinBlue alpha:0.0] CGColor],
                nil];

layer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                   nil];

layer.startPoint        = CGPointMake(0, 0);
layer.frame             = button.layer.bounds;

layer.endPoint          = CGPointMake(0, 1);
layer.contentsGravity   = kCAGravityResize;
[button.layer insertSublayer:layer below:button.titleLabel.layer];

button.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
```

As you can see , a nice touch would be to have some global int vars that define the RGB of the app's skin. This way you can modify it in seconds.

So , by using this way you are imune to the changes that Apple makes over SDK versions. 
And you can customize it in any way that you want , achieving much more than you could ever get in IB.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!